# Is Kerberos Authentication supported in WASB in Azure VM?

Tags: java, azure, authentication, kerberos

I have created Linux Azure VM and running Java application on it. Then I created HDInsight Spark Cluster which has hdfs, yarn, spark, etc.

I have connected VM with Spark cluster using the Storage Access Key in core-site.xml on VM.

core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.key.YOUR_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>Storage_Access_Key</value>
</property>
```

and I am able to authenticate my application with above. But I want to authenticate for my JAVA application using Kerberos in Azure Blob Storage (WASB) on Azure VM.

Is there any possible options and documentation for it ? Kindly help me

Comment: @Walter Kindly help me to answer this ?

Comment: Is WASB == blob storage? If so, i'm not quite sure we understand the requirement here, care to be a little more specific?

Answer (score 1):

First, please make sure that the Kerberos authentication has been configured for HDInsight. If not sure, please refer to the hortonworks offical documents https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.2.1/bk_Ambari_Security_Guide/content/ch_configuring_amb_hdp_for_kerberos.html to do it.

Second, you can try to refer to the Hadoop offical [document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-auth/Configuration.html) for Authentication with Kerberos to configure your webapp.

Or you can manually authenticate with Kerberos in programming as below.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration 

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("<username>", "/path/to/kerberos.keytab");
```

Then

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

As reference, you also can refer to the third party blogs([1](http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/02/14/a-secure-hdfs-client-example/), [2](http://dewoods.com/blog/hadoop-kerberos-guide)) to know more details.